# How do I display questions to the user on a screen (turtle), instead of in the terminal?

Tags: python, user-input, python-turtle

I'm making a program which solves f.e. the quadratic formula.
However I would like to ask the variables (A,B,C) in a screen with "import turtle" instead of in the terminal.
I know how to make a screen: background color; amount of pixels; etc.
But I don't know how to ask the variables and display the answer on that screen.

This is the code:

```
import math
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("VKV by @Boldarcticwolf")
wn.bgcolor("green")
wn.setup(width=600, height=600)


A = int(input("What is A? "))
B = int(input("What is B? "))
C = int(input("What is C? "))

D = (B * B) - (4 * A * C)
    
if D < 0: 
    print('D is', D)
       
elif D == 0:
    X1 = (-1 * B) / (2 * A)
    print('D is 0 and x is', X )
    
elif D > 0:
    X1 = ((-1 * B) + math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * A)
    X2 = ((-1 * B) - math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * A)
    print('D is', D, ', X1 is', X1, 'and X2 is', X2)
```

This brings up a screen and asks the variables but doesn't ask them on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use turtle.textinput to pop a dialog for user input.

```
import math
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("VKV by @Boldarcticwolf")
wn.bgcolor("green")
wn.setup(width=600, height=600)


A = int(turtle.textinput('A value',"What is A? "))
B = int(turtle.textinput('B value',"What is B? "))
C = int(turtle.textinput('C value',"What is C? "))

D = (B * B) - (4 * A * C)
    
if D < 0: 
    turtle.write(f'D is{D}', font=('Courier', 30, 'italic'), align='center' )
       
elif D == 0:
    X1 = (-1 * B) / (2 * A)
    turtle.write(f'D is 0 and {X1} is {X1}', font=('Courier', 30, 'italic'), align='center' )
    
elif D > 0:
    X1 = ((-1 * B) + math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * A)
    X2 = ((-1 * B) - math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * A)
    turtle.write(f'D is {D}, X1 is{X1} and and X2 is {X2}', font=('Courier', 30, 'italic'), align='center' )
    
wn.exitonclick()
```

Note, you should probably add some sort of validation, or use try/except, to check the use has actually entered a numeric value.

Comment: And how would I after that print the answer in the turtle?

Comment: You can use turtle.write for that, i've updated the anser.